# How do I use "::" as delimiter with other delimiters

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a dat file and I am struggling with split in Java. I think I am missing something basic but I have no idea what, below is my two classes and my test file. I can get it to use all of the delimiters by using brackets and pipes but I want it to treat :: together so that when it goes through the text it treats :: as one delimiter. Right now it is treating it as two instances of : and giving me a black space in my result.

Driver.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Driver
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<MovieInfo> mData = new ArrayList<>();

        File rData = new File("test.dat");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(rData);

        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            String[] data = scanner.nextLine().split("[::|(|)]"); //this is where my issue is

            String tempId = data[0];
            String tempName = data[1];
            String tempYear = data[2];
            String tempGenres = data[3];

            MovieInfo tempMInfo = new MovieInfo(tempId, tempName, tempYear, tempGenres);

            mData.add(tempMInfo);
        }

        for (MovieInfo each:mData)

        System.out.println(each);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

MovieInfo.java

```
public class MovieInfo {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String year;
    private String genres;

    public MovieInfo(String id, String name, String year, String genres)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.genres = genres;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "ID #: " + id + "\n" + "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Year: " + year + "\n" + "Genres: " + genres;
    }

}
```

test.dat

```
1::Toy Story (1995)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
2::Jumanji (1995)::Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3::Grumpier Old Men (1995)::Comedy|Romance
4::Waiting to Exhale (1995)::Comedy|Drama
5::Father of the Bride Part II (1995)::Comedy
6::Heat (1995)::Action|Crime|Thriller
7::Sabrina (1995)::Comedy|Romance
8::Tom and Huck (1995)::Adventure|Children's
9::Sudden Death (1995)::Action
10::GoldenEye (1995)::Action|Adventure|Thriller
```

output

```
ID #: 1
Name: 
Year: Toy Story 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 2
Name: 
Year: Jumanji 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 3
Name: 
Year: Grumpier Old Men 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 4
Name: 
Year: Waiting to Exhale 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 5
Name: 
Year: Father of the Bride Part II 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 6
Name: 
Year: Heat 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 7
Name: 
Year: Sabrina 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 8
Name: 
Year: Tom and Huck 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 9
Name: 
Year: Sudden Death 
Genres: 1995
ID #: 10
Name: 
Year: GoldenEye 
Genres: 1995
done
```

As you can see from my output it is putting a blank for name and shifting down the rest of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's ignoring the double-colon in your version is that you're creating a character class, by using the brackets. Duplicate characters in character classes are ignored. Your regex will also result in it treating `(` and `)` as delimiters since they too are included in the class.

Really what you appear to want is to split the string at all occurrences of a double colon and at all occurrences of a pipe. Writing this as a straightforward regex, you get `split("::|\\|")`

- double colon (`::`) or (`|`) pipe (`\\|`)
- since pipe is a reserved character in a regex, you have to escape this character when you don't want it to mean "or"
- to escape in Java regexes, use a double backslash

Comment: I wanted to use ( and ) as delimiters as well, but your explination solved my problem, I ended up using 

     ("::|\\(|\\)|\\|")

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java docs split function takes a regex string. Using the following should work fine - Split(":{2} | \|"). Explanation of regex match exactly 2 instances of : and first backslash to escape the backslash symbol and second to escape the | symbol. | symbol in the middle means alternate match. So string "hello::world|cool" when split by above regex should give you an array of three strings.